# OpenVPN connection dependency in Windows 10 service

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, services

I am running the OpenVPN client service on a Windows 10 machine. It's set to automatic and starts and connects to the VPN server on boot, as expected. On my Linux machine I can see the individual daemons that run for each connection in my services, as a list like:

```
├─system-openvpn.slice
│ └─openvpn@<vpn-config-name>.service
│   └─12935 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-<vpn-config-name> --status /
```

I then run another service that requires the VPN connection to be established and in Linux I can set a dependency on `openvpn@<vpn-config-name>` inside that service. I would like to do the same for the Windows service but I can not find the equivalent connection specific service *id* that I need to add.

Is there a standard way to achieve this in Windows?

Comment: Nicely answered already in [How to add dependency on a Windows Service AFTER the service is installed - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed)

Comment: @DavidPostill The problem here is I don't know how to find the particular service name. I know how to add a dependency but in my service list I can only see OpenVPNService which is the general VPN client tool. I want to set the dependency to the specific VPN tunnel that's defined in a specific config file.